# Laravel 4.2 - Route not working for searchbar

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have created a `Form` in a `blade` template. This form sends a `POST` request to `search.postQuery`, so I can get the search query and then do something with it and return a `View`.

This is the route I have defined:

```
Route::post('/search/{query}', ['as' => 'search.postQuery', 'uses' => 'SearchController@postQuery'])->where('query', '[a-zA-Z0-9]+');
```

My form looks like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'route' => array('search.postQuery')) }}
{{ Form::text('searchQuery') }}
{{ Form::submit('Zoeken!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the method the route calls on `POST`:

```
 public function postQuery($query)
 {
        var_dump("Landed here");
 }
```

And finally, the error Laravel poses me with is a `NotFoundHttpException`.
I also discovered that Laravel is constructing a rather strange URL when I press submit: `http://homestead.app/search/%7Bquery%7D`

What am I doing wrong? As to my knowledge, I'm not doing something very strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your error

```
  {{ Form::open(array('route'=>'search.postQuery','method' => 'POST')) }}
  {{ Form::text('searchQuery') }}
  {{ Form::submit('Zoeken!') }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution did not solve my error. Also the URL is getting a strange format when sent: `http://homestead.app/search/%7Bquery%7D`

Comment: Have you tried changing  your route like Route::post('/search/{query}', 'SearchController@postQuery');  remove the other parameters and see what happens

Comment: It is working now! It lands to the var_dump in `postQuery`. I only have one question left now, that is how I can get the URL to display the searchQuery instead of the link from my first comment?

**edit** When var_dumping parameter `$query` in the method, it's echoing literally `{query}`.

Comment: remove the {query} since its a post request and leave the route as Route::post('/search','SearchController@postQuery');. then try and see

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for SearchController::postQuery()`
So I guess Laravel is now missing the relation between the Form/route/Controller?

Comment: Solved by using `Input::all()` instead of a method parameter.